# What is the name of this design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, php

Magento has a class called `Varien_Object` with a pattern I'm trying to identify. The pattern creates hidden data and allows access to it but the  main difference between this and a normal facade is that methods are dynamically created to allow access to this data.

Here's a (very rough) example of pattern.

```
$vo = new Varien_Object();

// The Varian_Object allows data to be set using the "setData" method.
$vo->setData('something', 'one');
$vo->getData('something'); // -> "one"

// Null is returned if the data isn't recognised.
$vo->getData('does_not_exist'); // -> null

// But here's the pattern I'm curious about. By default, the Varien_Object does
// not have a "setSomethingElse" method.
$vo->setSomethingElse('two');
// Behind the scenes, the method name is checked and converted. The line above 
// is equivalent to this:
$vo->setData('something_else', 'two');
```

The magic `set` method has equivalent methods for `get`, `has` and `uns` ("delete").

My question is: **does this pattern have a name** and, if so, what is it?

Comment: It does not have a name. Not everything you see is a design patern. This is merely a construct the language (PHP) has and allows you to use. But, coming from a PHP background, I don't recommend you to use magic methods very often, because they are trickier to debug than the regular (be it accessors or specified methods) aproach.

Comment: @DavidPacker: looks like that comment would be the best answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts here - handle an undefined method call.

The first part is a means by which the language allows an object to handle a call to a method which was not defined. On Rosetta it's called  '[Respond to an unknown method call](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call)'. Language capabilities are the opposite of design patterns - patterns exist to work around lack of capabilities in languages.

The second part is to use the unknown method call capability to turn a call of the form `setFoo(x)` to a dictionary entry `"Foo" -> x`. I'm not aware of this being a named pattern; similar use cases in the other languages I know either are static and would use a dictionary here, or are fully dynamic and allow ad-hoc properties to be added.